# geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped

Tags: rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,i saw in a public code that they uesd a **Vector3Stamped** to Publish function for odometry
like this

---

```
speed_msg.header.stamp = nh.now(); 
  speed_msg.vector.x = speed_act_left; 
  speed_msg.vector.y = speed_act_right; 
  speed_msg.vector.z = time / 10; 
  speed_pub.publish(&speed_msg);
  nh.spinOnce();
```

---

The **quastion** what is the **Vector3Stamped** and how we can publisth the data for **odometry**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404697/geometry_msgs/vector3stamped/) by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2022-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The question what is the Vector3Stamped

The `geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped` message represents a `Vector3` with reference coordinate frame and timestamp. For example, consider your robot moving and publishing its position in 3D as a Vector (x, y, z). This Vector makes sense only when you define a reference coordinate system called a coordinate frame. Because the robot is publishing its position while moving, you need to track the time. Therefore, given 2 `Vector3`, you simply check their time value to differentiate between them. This time value is called timestamp.

The `geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped.msg` is defined as following:

```
# Header contains reference coordinate frame and timestamp
std_msgs/Header header
geometry_msgs/Vector3 vector
```

Please feel free to check [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/lunar/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Vector3Stamped.html).

> how we can publish the data for odometry

Publishing odometry information over ROS is generally done using `nav_msgs/Odometry.msg`. The `nav_msgs/Odometry.msg` represents an estimate of a position and velocity in free space. Please check [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) for the message definition. There is an excellent tutorial titled "Publishing Odometry Information over ROS." Please check [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) to view this tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on 2022-08-07**:
Thanks ravi

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-07**:
You are welcome. If the above post answers your issue, I recommend you to click on the accept button to show that question is solved.